# JSF Form Submit works in FF but not in IE

Tags: jsf, internet-explorer-8, form-submit

I have a simple Form with an inputText and a commandButton.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="xyz" value="#{viewImpl.field}" onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="setDefaultText(this)" />
    <h:commandButton action="#{viewImpl.method}"/>
</h:form>
```

If I press on the commandButton the form is submitted correctly.
But if I hit enter, still being in the inputText-Field the page reloads, but the method is not called (server is in debug mode with activated breakpoints).

Important: This only happens in IE 8. It works perfectly fine in Firefox.
Any clue on how I can fix this?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known problem with one-field forms in IE. Pressing the enter key won't trigger the first-next button of the form and hence its name=value pair won't appear in the request parameter map and hence JSF can't identify the button in order to queue the action event.

One of the ways to fix this is to add a second but invisible input field to the very same form.

```
<input type="text" name="dummy" style="display: none;" />
```

This will cause IE to send the name=value pair of the first-next button as well.

Comment: I think that another sensible alternative would be to bind a custom keyup listener to an input field that identifies enter key and triggers command button click in that case.

Comment: @skuntsel: Yes, but this breaks if JS is disabled. My answer provides a way which works in all circumstances.

Comment: Agreed. The comment was intended as a remark and not as something that undermines your answer :)